# Copy table structure into new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to copy the structure of a table into a new table, without data, including all keys and constraints?

Comment: Select * Into NewTableName From OldTableName Where 1 = 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table

Answer (score 237):

For a simple schema copy use the like clause.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name (LIKE old_table_name INCLUDING ALL);
```

Comment: Worth noting you can also add new columns when using the like syntax:
`CREATE TABLE new (like old, extra_column text);`

Comment: @BradKoch is it possible to add extra constraints within this statement? Or it should be a separate one?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It depends, check the [create table docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) for full details.  You can easily add check and foreign key constraints using this syntax, just like with any other create statement, but I'm not sure whether column level constraints like not null can be applied without a subsequent alter.

Comment: Tried just now. Didn't copy foreign-key constraints and triggers (PostgreSQL 9.2).

Comment: Like the other answer, this works but has caveats. Besides the issue with FKs, this also causes the tables to share any sequences for serial cols. I'd just do this manually if possible. In most situations it's not hard to grab the CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX, etc commands for one table and change the names accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to include a subset of columns *with* structure? something like `CREATE TABLE meta.dest
(LIKE (SELECT date_time, is_update_finished FROM meta.source) INCLUDING ALL);`? it doesn't work

Comment: call me crazy, but wouldnt 'including all' mean, you know, 'include data'?

Comment: @johnk My educated guess would be - since this is a DDL (Data Defining Language) syntax the all here can only refer to the schema/structure and not the actual data.

Answer (score 96):

Well, the closest you can get with SQL is:

```
create table new (
    like old
    including defaults
    including constraints
    including indexes
);
```

But it will not copy everything. The most important things that are missing are FOREIGN KEYs. Also - triggers are also not copied. Not sure about other things.

Another way is to dump the table structure, change it's name in dump, and load it again:

```
pg_dump -s -t old databases | sed 's/old/new/g' | psql
```

But beware, that such simplistic sed will also change old to new in other places (for example if you have in your table column named "is_scolded" it will become "is_scnewed").

The question really is rather: why do you need it - because for various purposes, I would use different techniques.

Comment: Note: `including constraints` does not work on PostgreSQL 8.3

Comment: Worked like a charm in Postgres 9.3 :)

Comment: Best answer. Just beware that if you have a "serial" value or some other column defaulting to a sequence, it'll use the same sequence as the old table! So if you insert stuff into either table, it'll increment for both.

Comment: @sudo what's the solution for this? I want to create a new table but I also want to drop the old table which is throwing an error to me `PSQLException: ERROR: cannot drop table because other objects depend on it
  Detail: default value for column id of table depends on sequence`

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli Haven't tried this myself, but supposedly serials are implemented as default values + sequence, so you can do `ALTER TABLE yourtable ALTER COLUMN serialcol DROP DEFAULT;`. Then follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres to add a new sequence if you want.

Answer (score 39):

To copy a table completely, the short form using the TABLE command can also be used:

```
CREATE TABLE films2 AS
    TABLE films
    WITH NO DATA;
```

More details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this copies the data as well - from what I understand the question is about copying just the schema

Comment:  ids are NULL in the new table and doesn't copy default values.

Comment: Note that this won't copy constraints like NOT NULL.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) - by far the easiest way to do what you want.
Right-click on table, Scripts - Create.

Comment: I only have access to phpPgAdmin; I don't own the server.

Comment: Fair enough. In phpPgAdmin: navigate to the table, click Export, select "Structure Only" and you have your script

Comment: I'm pretty sure their must be a bug in this install - it just shows a blank page in the right frame when I do that :/

Comment: Did you try both "show" or "download" options? If both don't work then yes, it might be a bug. If so, you'll need to do it via SQL, take a look at link in Dav's answer.

Comment: Download just gives me an empty file.

Comment: Most likely an installation error - perhaps phppgadmin is unable to access the pg_dump binary which it uses to get the structure.

Comment: @Magnus - good call. There was a recent change to the server which required me to switch to absolute paths in exec(). I'll notify the appropriate people.

Answer (score 11):

How about

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table_copy AS (SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE 1 = 2)
```

[postgresql.org answer](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/003101c38d05$e9c1c910$7801a8c0@Louise)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't preserve keys, constraints, or defaults.

Comment: A better way to express 'WHERE 1=2' would be 'WHERE false' or no WHERE clause at all, but 'LIMIT 0 ' instead.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
pg_dump dbname -s -t table_to_clone > /tmp/temp.sql
```

Than sed or vim of the file to change the table name and related stuff. Often is enough to replace *table_to_clone* with *table_new_name*.

At creation, I usually prefix with table name indexes and triggers, so at this point I have nothing more to do.

Now, from `psql`:

```
begin work;
\i /tmp/temp.sql
```

In this way, only if everything is fine I:

```
commit
```

and the game is done!