# How to create a copy of table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to save a copy of specific table with it's data.
All I care is the structure and data. I don't want to copy the keys nor constrains.

I read this answer [Copy table structure into new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220453/copy-table-structure-into-new-table)  but it's not quite what I need.

How it can be done?

Comment: `create table copy_table as select * from original table` ?..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are probably looking for [CREATE TABLE AS SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html), e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE copy_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Comment: "original table" ---> original_table ;-)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE copy_table AS TABLE original_table;` - shorthand version

Comment: yes, but `TABLE` is much less flexible than `SELECT` - I would prefer answering it with select, as you can add any `where` or whatever to a statement, not just `limit` or what the possible option list it

Comment: and if you just want the table structure, without the data you can add `WHERE 1=0`