# postgresql COPY TABLE not including table rows

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

How do I create a COPY of a table without including any of the rows?

I want to copy a table, delete all of the rows, update a csv file to the copied table using csv copy_expert, and then use the copied table to update the original table.

I'm using copy_table = """SELECT (Top 0) into temp FROM original.;"""
But it's giving an error for postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same question as [Copy table structure into new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220453/copy-table-structure-into-new-table)? Add a LIKE clause to your CREATE TABLE statement.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name ( LIKE old_table_name INCLUDING ALL )
```

Comment: Hi Terry. Thanks, Does this work as well?         """SELECT Top 0 * into "NewTable" FROM "ExistingTable";"""

Comment: I wouldn't think so, use LIMIT instead. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-selectinto.html