# Cloning a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if there is a command to clone a table in PostgreSQL. By cloning I mean with the same schema, so that it already identifies the primary key, foreign keys (if applicable), etc.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy table structure into new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220453/copy-table-structure-into-new-table)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is here, in the deep cloning part of the article

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-clone-tables-in-sql-dd29586ec89c